# PHPMyAdmin Missing Columns in Export

Tags: phpmyadmin

I export a table from my server, and it looks like this...

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `actions` (
  `aid` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Primary Key: Unique actions ID.',
  `type` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'The object that that action acts on (node, user, comment, system or custom types.)',
  `callback` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'The callback function that executes when the action runs.',
  `parameters` longblob NOT NULL COMMENT 'Parameters to be passed to the callback function.',
  `label` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Label of the action.',
  PRIMARY KEY (`aid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Stores action information.';
```

However, I have just reinstalled WAMP, and when I export from there, it looks like this....

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `actions` (
  `aid` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'COMMENT
) ;
```

This is missing all of the columns, and when trying to import, has the error...

`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 3`

Is there anything I should be setting here? Ive installed WAMP a few times before, and the default SQL export has always been fine. The databases are exactly the same, the one on WAMP just ignores loads of columns and data when exporting. I have definitely selected all table structure and data for export.

Comment: something's corrupted. it's not just missing fields, it's just chopping off everything after the first `comment`.

Comment: Re-install WAMP then maybe? Or revert to another version of PHPmyadmin?

Comment: Just uninstalled, and reinstalled, and the same thing is happening. I will try reverting to the 32 bit version.

Comment: Same thing happens with the 32 bit version. Losing patience now!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

God knows why but the export in Phpmyadmin is messed up.

I ssh'd to msql5.7.11/bin and used `mysqldump --databases test > dump.sql` instead

Answer (score 0):

in my case it was caused by incorrectly formed table (generated from migration)

- i was unable to duplicate the table and it showed the warning
- i fixed the table form (finally able to duplicate) and it exported correctly